# Declare variable for ConcurrentDictionary.Select()

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a simple ConcurrentDictionary that I'm trying to select a subset of the values.

I'm using this code and the only way I can get it to work is var to declare testStudents. What would be the proper declaration for this code? I tried List and IEnumratable but they didn't work.

```
            public ConcurrentDictionary<string, Student> _Student = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Student>();

            var testStudents = this._Student.Values.Select( s => s.Name = "jack");
```

Comment: It looks like its a List<string>? Oh and materialise it by calling .ToList() on it and inspecting testStudents to be sure. In fact, are you setting the name of each Student to jack?

Comment: I assume you intend to use `Where(s => s.Name == "jack")`. In that case `testStudents` will be an `IEnumerable<Student>`. Your current expression sets the name of each value to "jack" and evaluates to a string.

Comment: IEnumerable<string>....but you can leave var alone as the compiler will infer the correct type.

Comment: `Select` means map collection (each element must be converted to another element by mapping function). `Where` means filter collection by condition.

Comment: Probably, you want something like `var testStudents = this._Student.Values.Where( s => s.Name = "jack");`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. Looks like I'm using the wrong method. The `Where` method is what I needed to use.

```
IEnumerable<Student> testStudents
     = this._Student.Values.Where( s => s.Name = "jack");
```